# parse characters after backslash like \a, \s, \n

Tags: c++, parsing, escaping, sequence, backslash

I need to parse strings simmilar to "{ \sel \b \a }==>3'001\y1'1" with c++.
I have to get the inputnames. These are the ones after the . I tried iterating over the string searching for '\', then copy all chars after \ until " " (space).

```
for (i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) { 

                if (str[i] == '\\') {
                    for (j = i + 1; j < str.size(); j++) {
                        if (str[j] == ' ') { 
                            start = i;
                            end = j; // then copy chars i to j.
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But unfortunately \ implicates an escape sequence and this is not working. 
Is there a quick solution for this problem? thx

Comment: I don't see the problem with the code you show. Using double backslashes escapes the backslash so you can search for it. With the code you show, ***how*** is it "not working"? Have you tried debugging your code, have you tried step through the code line by line in a debugger? Please elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Sorry but what is the problem?

Comment: I suspect your start is off by one and now includes the backslash (should be `start = i + 1;`), other than that your code looks fine. But your question isn't really clear...